# rails, using devise gem for multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

i try to search on web and stackoverflow but any answer is about my problem :S
I have a website and now want to create new service under a path using this site.
like this;
my site => www.example.com
my new service => www.example.com/service, www.example.com/service/#######/#####
I have a user model on my site and authenticating with devise gem.
Now i have to create new user model that name is customer.
Customer and User models are completely different from each other.
How can i implement devise authentication for new Customer model?

Comment: Is your requirement to provide central *authentication* for distinctly different entities, or is it closer to think about the problem as "a person comes to the site and once they have logged in, I want to *authorize* them to have access to specific functions."  Devise (and Rails' built-in `has_secure_password`) both assume that a "user" is just an entity that has some sort of identifier, e.g. email, and a password, and that there are many common things this user will do in the process of registration, login, pw reset, etc -- this is authentication; what they can do afterwards is authorization.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you must use a role gem for this purpose.

You can use https://github.com/ryanb/cancan or https://github.com/kristianmandrup/cantango

For routes you can use namespaces:

```
namespace :service do
 #routes here
end
```

Best Regards!

Comment: i can imagine this routing type. But my question is about devise and multiple implemantation on single site.